# Can anyone explain how caller method is matching correctly with the regex in the following code snippet

Tags: ruby

Here I am trying to check which method is calling the "trxn_message" method by using a case statement with caller[0].  How is this working?. can someone help me on this ?

I am using ruby 2.5.1

```
def trxn_message(attributes, records = nil)
        #binding.pry
        case caller[0]
        when /insert/
            binding.pry
            puts "#{post_trxn_count} new record created: #{attributes}"  
        when /find/
            binding.pry
            puts "#{records.count} records found with criteria #{attributes}"
            records.each {|r| puts r} 
        when /delete/
            binding.pry
            puts "#{post_trxn_count} records with criteria #{attributes} deleted" 
        else
        end
    end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

caller[0] contains info about method, which call method, called `caller[0]`.
Format of caller[0] output is:

```
<filename>:<string number>:in `<method name>'
```

So, if your caller is 'find', then caller[0] will be:

```
filename.rb:10:in `find'
```

And regular expression, which you check as `/find/` return `'find'` - string, becomes as not falsey.

Comment: "as not falsy" - do you mean truthy?

Comment: Yes, of course. It's value is string, not boolean. Also can be interpreted as truthy.

Comment: Yes. you are right I got confused since I was using pry to inspect the value of caller[0].   Since I was under the scope of pry it add lot of other values in the caller array.